# how to populate array with data from file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have a FILE.txt with several columns:

```
A    12    13.9
B    51    55.4
C    20    22.1
D    89    96.8
```

I want to read them and to populate an array for each column, in order to get:

```
array LETTERS = [A, B, C, D]
array FIRST = [12, 51, 20, 89]
array SECOND = [13.9, 55.4, 22.1, 96.8]
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Have you tried out any code?

Comment: Please don't use all upper-case for normal variables. In Python such names are normally used for constants.

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
letters = []
first = []
second = []

for line in f:
    columns = line.split()
    letters.append(columns[0])
    first.append(columns[1])
    second.append(columns[2])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for! The last two arrays are "first" and "second" though! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('FILE.txt','r') as f:
    Letters = []
    First = []
    Second = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        Letters.append(line.split()[0])
        First.append(line.split()[1])
        Second.append(line.split()[2])
```

Or, alternatively:

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    Letters = [line.split()[0] for line in data]
    First = [line.split()[1] for line in data]
    Second = [line.split()[2] for line in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration your types:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as d:
    content = d.readlines()

LETTERS = []
FIRST = []
SECOND = []

for el in content:
    cur_line = el.split()
    for i, l in enumerate([(LETTERS, str), (FIRST, int), (SECOND, float)]):
        l[0].append(l[1](cur_line[i]))

print LETTERS
print FIRST
print SECOND

>>> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> [12, 51, 20, 89]
>>> [13.9, 55.4, 22.1, 96.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to read the whole file into memory and use Python's convenient list manipulation facilities to create the columns.

```
with open(fname) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = [line.split() for line in data]
letters, first, second = zip(*data)

print(letters)
print(first)
print(second)
```

**output**

```
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
('12', '51', '20', '89')
('13.9', '55.4', '22.1', '96.8')
```

In `zip(*data)` the `*data` tells the `zip` function to get its arguments from the iterables in `data`, so `zip(*data)` creates a list of tuples from the successive elements of each of the lists  in `data`. (If those iterables are unequal in length then `zip` stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted).

The core of the above code can be condensed to:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    letters, first, second = zip(*[line.split() for line in f.readlines()])
```

although you may find the original version more readable.

If for some reason you need lists instead of tuples, replace the `zip(*data)` with

```
[list(t) for t in zip(*data)]
```

However, you should probably use tuples instead of lists here, unless you need to modify them: tuples are immutable but they are slightly more efficient than lists.

If you need to do arithmetic on the values in `first` and `second` (and that includes numeric comparisons) you will need to convert them to numeric types, eg

```
first = [int(s) for s in first]
second = [float(s) for s in second]
```